# Tags isNull and Active don't affect the project

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, ms-project

I'm trying to create a ms project xml file using c#. Everything is alright except bay the tasks that do not set the task mode to auto scheduled and the status to active. Here is the task element that my program is generating:

```
  <Task>
  <UID>10</UID>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <Name>Componente - Conversion</Name>
  <Active>1</Active>
  <Manual>0</Manual>
  <Type>2</Type>
  <isNull>0</isNull>
  <WBSLevel>1</WBSLevel>
  <Duration>PT1H0M00S</Duration>
  <ManualDuration>PT1H0M00S</ManualDuration>
  <CalendarUID>-1</CalendarUID>
  <IgnoreResourceCalendar>1</IgnoreResourceCalendar>
  <ExtendedAttribute>
    <FieldID>188743748</FieldID>
    <Value>1</Value>
  </ExtendedAttribute>
</Task>
```

but when I open the file in ms project 2010 the result is this:
[image]

Is there anything that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, the tags isNull and isPublished should be IsNull and IsPublished.